# Making a folder on one domain look like another domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, masking

I'm sure this has been asked and answered, a link to the answer would be awesome as I can't find what I need and I'm getting confused and frustrated!

I have a domain registered with GoDaddy: www.mybusiness.com

I have hosting with BlueHost and the files for the site are at www.myname.com/mybusiness. www.mybusiness.com is set up as a parked domain with BlueHost.

I've set up the redirect through BlueHost so when you type in www.mybusiness.com you go to www.myname.com/mybusiness. Great and good.

BUT, I want the URL to still show www.mybusiness.com...

How do I do this? If it's an htaccess answer do I do the htaccess stuff in www.myname.com/mybusiness? Or in www.myname.com?

Thank you and apologies if this is a duplicate!

Comment: So your domain `mybusiness.com` is registered with Godaddy but the site for that domain is hosted by BlueHost as a parked domain to `myname.com`, but you want `mybusiness.com` to show always. ¿Is that right? If so, ¿why don't you just make `mybusiness.com` the main domain and park the other one?

Comment: You have it exactly right! Except to a FOLDER on myname.com. There are several sites in different folders on myname.com. And the problem is, I have to do the same thing with another domain after this. =/ I actually have www.anothersite.com (that belongs to a friend I'm helping out) that will have to point to www.myname.com/anothersite, so I have to find a solution that will work more than once, if that makes sense.

Comment: You can't do it with htaccess while one is parked to the other. It will go into a loop. The way to do it is unparking the domains and then redirect in htacces the other one to `mybusiness.com`.

Comment: So, "un-assign" mybusiness.com from Blue Host? Two questions: 1) do I have to set up forwarding of mybusiness.com with GoDaddy? How will it know to forward to myname.com/mybusiness? And 2) what do I put in the htaccess? Does the htaccess go in myname.com/mybusiness?

Comment: `mybusinnes.com` is already pointing to BlueHost DNS, so you should not have to do anything. The content of the htaccess file (In the root of the site to be redirected) depends on the conditions you want for the redirection. You can select some specific paths, for example. You might open another thread with that question and parameters when you are ready. I'm sure you'll get several answers.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. The exact syntax of the htaccess stuff just boggles my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you are asking for a iframe? Or do you want http://example.com/sometext to be the same as http://example.org/sometext, and the directory is the same?

Comment: I want www.myname.com/mybusiness to stay exactly the same, everything is working great, but I want the url to say www.mybusiness.com. Right now www.mybusiness.com forwards to www.myname.com/mybusiness, which is perfect, but then you see www.myname.com/mybusiness in the url and I don't want that. www.mybusiness.com is just the domain, www.myname.com/mybusiness is where all the files are, I just want the url to say www.mybusiness.com.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying...I would use a iframe. Such as:
     <iframe src="http://myname.com/mybusiness" width="100%" height="100%" seamless></iframe>